# How to install Dropbox on Ubuntu 20.04 hard drive partition?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, dropbox

I want to install Dropbox on Ubuntu 20.04 but not in **home** directory. I prefer to directly install it in one of my hard drive partition, say, **/media/user/partition1/**. It will also be convenient for me if  Dropbox starts on system startup.

Comment: Install Dropbox. It has prefernces, where you can setup the directory.

Comment: This reference from Dropbox should help https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/desktop/move-dropbox-folder

Comment: " /media/user/partition1/" Not possible if this is NTFS due to the lack of support for linux permissions. We take security serious ;-)